# Maximum Edges Subgraph

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-hard

Given an (undirected) graph $G = (V,E)$ with $|V| = 2n$, what is the complexity of the problem of finding the subgraph $G' = (V',E')$ with $V' \subset V, |V'| = n$, such that the number of edges $|E'| = |\{(v,u) \in E\ |\ v,u \in V'\}|$ is maximized?

I feel like this is similar to Max-Bisection problem but focuses on the number of edges in a partition rather than edges between partitions, so maybe it is also NP-hard.

I'm particularly interested in the complexity of this problem for *unit disks graphs*, whether it is NP-hard, but any pointers or references to this kind of problem would be appreciated.

Comment: CLIQUE reduces to this problem so it is NP-hard in general, though this reduction cannot be applied to unit-disk graphs.

Comment: I see, do you mind showing me a reference for this? What is this problem I described called anyway?

Comment: The problem is a special case ($k=n/2$) of *Densest $k$-Subgraph*. Reduction of $k$-Clique is: add $k$ isolated vertices and a complete graph of size $n-k$ connected to all original vertices, so the density is maximal if and only if it is a $k$-Clique in the original graph + added $K_{n-k}$.